# bash date invalid date (-d 'feb 29 -3years')

Tags: bash, date

I was working with the date command today and discovered some behaviour I cannot explain (I skimmed through: ~$ info '(coreutils) date invocation' but didn't find anything) and hope that someone here might help me to understand why this is happening.

```
~$ date -u +%F -d "feb 28 -3years"
>> 2012-02-28
~$ date -u +%F -d "feb 29 2012"
>> 2012-02-29
~$ date -u +%F -d "feb 29 -3years"
>> date: invalid date ‘feb 29 -3years’
~$ date -u +%F -d 'feb 29 3 years ago'
>> date: invalid date ‘feb 29 3 years ago’
```

This is happening on all leap years/leap days (...2008/2012/2016...) and I just can't figure out why.

I' am running above commands on my Ubuntu Gnome Edition (15.04) and on my Server which runs Debian/Jessie.

Comment: It looks like date is trying to get Feb 29 2015 before subtracting 3 years, and there is no Feb 29 in 2015

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda hacky but a good way of getting the last day of the month is to go to the first day of the next month, then back by one day:

```
$ date -u +%F -d "mar 1 -3years -1day"
2012-02-29
```

I don't claim to know how the `date` command is implemented but it stands to reason that `feb 29` is the first part of the string that is interpreted, before making the subtractions. So the safest thing to do is to use a date that is always valid, then make a series of subtractions.

Comment: This helps if one is looking for the leap days I encountered this behaviour while testing a script I wrote to give out all days of a month of a given year. I just switched to use years like 2014,2015,2016 and so on to workaround it. [I read] (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings) But couldn't find any hints besides the last sentence.